# Building OpenH264 library with android NDK19 fails

Tags: android-ndk, lib, ndk-build, openh264

I need to build openh264 library for android. I downloaded from official webpage(https://github.com/cisco/openh264).

I'm following the same steps. It's working with android **ndk15**, not working with latest **ndk19**. Because they have removed the **stlport** from new ndk19. using ndk15 build library  is not working for latest android OS. so I need to build with ndk19.

while building with ndk19, its giving the error like,

> Android NDK: APP_STL stlport_shared is no longer supported. Please
>   switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See
>   https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more
>   information.    .  Stop. build/platform-android.mk:51: *** Compiler
>   not found, bad NDKROOT or ARCH?.  Stop.

can anyone please help me out of this issue?

Comment: Did you do what the error message told you to do?

Comment: "using ndk15 build library is not working for latest android OS" - why is that? Even though NDK r15 might not have headers/libs specifically for the latest versions, you definitely should be able to build code using the older NDK and run it on the latest android versions. When building for one android version, it should implicitly work on any newer version as well.

Comment: NandhaKumar did you solve the problem?